# Access forbidden for OSX Apache from external device

Tags: macos, apache, server

I've been stuck on this for days. After upgrading to Yosemite, I can no longer access my Apache webserver from any device on my home network, except for the device running it (my MBP). I get a 403 Forbidden when accessing from my PS4, smartphone, or any other device.

A lot of people seem to have similar problems when trying to access it from localhost, but that works fine for me. It's external access that is being denied.

To test, I changed my httpd.conf to "Require all allowed" for my entire filesystem, but then I got a "File not found" error on those external devices. So this makes me think it's not a firewall issue. What could it be?

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? I have the same problem with Yosemite and Server 5.0.4